# UITableView editing: Cell edits, but delete button does not show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, edit

Here is the code:

```
-(void)buttonEditPressed:(id)sender{

    if(_tableView.isEditing){

        [_tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
        [_buttonEdit setTitle:@"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    } else {

        [_tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [_buttonEdit setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    [_tableView reloadData];

}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DLog(@"");
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //Delete the rows at the Indexpath.

    //edit data model 

    [_tableView reloadData];

}
```

here is the result:
[image]
[image]

Swipe delete works. When the edit button is pressed however, the cell animates to the right displaying the space for the red delete button on the left, but that button never appears!

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell

it's great documented, easy to use and great for what you want.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I'd rather honestly just manually create a button then rather than use a whole new library =/ thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: the problem in your code is that you don't define any view/button for left side..

Comment: oh.. wait.. now I got it.. in the edit state.. the delete buttons doesn't appear.. it should appear a select box.. and you must implement a button to delete all the indexPaths selected. I'm not sure honestly how to do that.. try to look an other apps that uses this feature